# Refer to a macro variable

Tags: loops, variables, sas, sas-macro

Let's say I have a table with 10 variables: var1, var2... var10 and I want to create other 9 variables : coef1, coef2.... coef9 from the 10 initial variable like:

```
coef1 = var2 gt .,
coef2 = var3 gt .,
...
coef9 = var10 gt .,
```

I try the code like:

```
%macro mymacro;
%do i = 1 %to 9;
 data mydata;
  set mydata;
  coef&i = var&i+1 gt .,
 run;
%end;
%mend;

%mymacro;
```

But it doesn't work, I guess the problem is that SAS could not resolve the var&i+1. What am I supposed to solve it?

Comment: Why macro variables? Use Arrays instead.

Comment: But in case I have 100 variables, it will be quicker with macro variable? I imagine if I use arrays, I have to declare all?

Comment: The same calculation has to occur whether it's macro or array. What do you mean you need to declare all? There are many ways to use short cut variable lists like the colon operator.  `array myVars(*) coef:;` is for all variables that start with coef.

Comment: Ah ok I got it, I will try with array, but does loop work in this case?

Comment: Why are you using `var2 GT .`?  Note that will be true when VAR2 has special missing values `.A` to `.Z` since they are larger than regular missing value `.`.  Did you want to use `not missing(var2)` instead?

Answer (score 3):

Use an array instead of macro for looping over variables. Or alternatively restructure your data to a long format and use that formatting.

```
data want;
set have;

array coef(*) coef:;
array _var(*) var2-var100;

do i=1 to 99;
  coef(i) = _var(i+1) gt .;
end;

run;
```

Comment: Why do we have to add _ before var?

Comment: VAR() is a function as well for variance, so I used _var to help differentiate. You can use whatever variable name you want though.

Comment: Just to be picky... `_var` is the array name and `var2-var100` are variable names.  @Reeza chose array name `_var` in order to avoid a naming collision with either a SAS function name *or* data set variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You should use macro `%do` inside data step and `%eval` to calculate macro value:

```
%macro mymacro;

 data mydata;
  set mydata;
  %do i = 1 %to 9;
     coef&i = var%eval(&i+1) gt .;
  %end;
 run;

%mend;

%mymacro;
```